# SQL: How to make a concant query independent of the DB

Tags: mysql, sqlite, concatenation

I need to concat two fields in a SQL sentence, and I'm using the same sentences for both MySQL and SQLite in a java app using JDBC.

It turns out both MySQL and SQLite have different and not compatible concat operators:

- MySQL uses "CONCAT(smth, smth)"
- SQLite uses "smth || smth".

Until now I've managed to use the same sentence for both DBs, so now I need either a way to find a concat operator independent from MySQL and SQLite; or detect dynamically in my java application if the sentence is going to be executed in either MySQL or SQLite.

I also can add a param in my java method, the one that contains the SQL Query, to know if I'm using MySQL or SQLite, but I don't really like this last solution.

Do you guys have any idea about how to make an independent concat operator? or any other idea at all?

Thanks.

Comment: I remember writing different PLSQL / Whatever procedures for this kind of thing (mysql and postgresql) but then I started switching that particular task to the client code. I've been happier ever since.

Comment: @user2256799. Were you able to accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do it with the mode [PIPES_AS_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) in the mysql side, to make the || behave similar as in sqlite. See also [this article](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/03/09/sql-concatenation-blues/) for additional information